# Calculate uptime from timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have table that saving heartbeat with timestamps. If there is no heartbeat it skip saving, so there is only timestamps when was endpoint live.

How can I calculate last uptime block from timestamps? **If it there 5 minute gap between timestamps it count's like block end/start.**

**Table with timestamps**

```
+------------+----------------------+
|    user    |         date         |
+------------+----------------------+
| 5          |  2017-11-22 16:10:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 16:11:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 16:12:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 16:13:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:05:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:06:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:07:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:13:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:14:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:15:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:16:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:17:01 |
| 5          |  2017-11-22 19:18:01 |
+------------+----------------------+
```

**Result**

```
Last uptime was from 19:13:01 - now() - 00:05:00
```

Thanks with help or any recommendation.

Comment: pure punt but what about Using something like `MIN` and `MAX` along with [`timestampdiff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to process values?

Comment: [this topic should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804713/mysql-select-last-full-5-minute-interval)

Comment: What is the reason behind doing this : `19:13:01 - now() - 00:05:00`?

Comment: @Harshil its only text result .. end result could be only "00:05:00"

Comment: @Martin not helped :/

Comment: ok. But why do you want to check with `19:13:01` when the last timestamp is `19:18:01`.

Comment: @Harshil the last one is 19:18:01 but I need to select min timestamp from last time block that ends 19:18:01 and calculate time between them.

now() is 19:19:01

Comment: You can get the unixtimestamp of the dates, and subtract that by that value modulus 5 minutes (300) and group by that value. It will snap each timestamps to 5 minute intervals. from_unixtimestamp(unix_timestamp(date) - (unix_timestamp(date)%300)) I believe.